# How to make /bin/ps, called with aux as its argument, write to a file?

Tags: firefox, logging, redirect, javascript, firefox-extensions

Is there a command line argument I can pass to `/bin/ps -aux` to make it write its output to a file?

---

edit:
To resimulate my issue:

1. Open firefox
2. Enable developer preferences (or as shortcut install addon [DevPrefs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devprefs/))
3. Open Scratchpad by press Shift + F4
4. In menu bar to go "Browser" menu and click on "Environment"
5. Now in scratchpad code paste this code, this code will find ps and then run it with command line options of `aux` and `>PATH_TO_DESKTOP_me.txt`

   ```
   var thisWin = Services.ww.activeWindow;
   var env = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/environment;1'].getService(Ci.nsIEnvironment);

   var psCommand = 'ps';
   var paths = env.get('PATH').split(':');
   var len = paths.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       try {
           var fullyQualified = new FileUtils.File(OS.Path.join(paths[i], psCommand));
           console.log('fullyQualified:', fullyQualified.path)
           if (fullyQualified.exists()) {
               var ps = fullyQualified;
               break;
           }
       } catch (e) {
           // keep checking PATH if we run into NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH
       }
   }

   if (!ps) {
       console.error("Error: a task list executable not found on filesystem");
       thisWin.alert('Error: a task list executable not found on filesystem');
     throw new Error("Error: a task list executable not found on filesystem");
   }

   thisWin.alert('path to ps: "' + ps.path + '"');

   var process = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
   process.init(ps);

   var procFinned = {
       observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
               thisWin.alert('ps completed');
       }
   };

   var filePathToOutputTo = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'me.txt');
   thisWin.alert('will write to file path: "' + filePathToOutputTo + '"');
   var args = ['aux', '>' + filePathToOutputTo];
   var a = process.runAsync(args, args.length, procFinned);
   ```
6. Then press Ctrl + R to run the code, or can do same from going to "Execute" menu and clicking "Run".

So the code launches ps process with is right here:

```
var args = ['aux', '>' + filePathToOutputTo];
var a = process.runAsync(args, args.length, procFinned);
```

- Combinations tried:

  - with quotes: `var args = ['aux', '>"' + filePathToOutputTo + '"'];`
  - as one array entryvalue with quotes `var args = ['aux >"' + filePathToOutputTo + '"'];`
  - as one array entry with no quotes: `var args = ['aux >' + filePathToOutputTo + ''];`

Comment: Talk about an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! The redirection is **not** an argument to a command. You should try redirecting the STDOUT from JavaScript. (I haven't touched JS in ages, let me look for a better way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With minimally touching JavaScript (from my side), I'd suggest this:

Run `bash` instead of `ps` - do all the searches and checks for `bash` and `ps`, and start the process for `bash` with arguments: `-c`, `ps.path + ' aux > '+ filePathToOutputTo`.

The overall command here should look like:

```
/bin/bash -c "/bin/ps aux > /path/to/output/file"
```

Comment: Thank you sir very much Ill go test this out and report back :)

Comment: Oh my gosh it worked!!! Thank you!!!!!! I actually had to pas it without the double quotes. The double quotes would prevent it from working. :(

Comment: @Noitidart ah, yes. The double quotes are to make it appear as a single argument, but that wouldn't be necessary, since the JavaScript library is doing that anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Looking through the list of command-line options accepted by `ps` in [the `ps` manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ps.1.html) (accessible there and by running `man ps`) reveals it doesn't have an option for logging to a file. Many commands do not. But you can still make it do what you want.

**[Redirecting with `>` or `>>`, as John1024 explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/522643/22949) sends the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) of your program to the file or device named to the right of `>`/`>>`.** It sounds like this is what you want.

However, if you want to write the output to a file and *also see it yourself* in the terminal, then you may wish to use the [`tee`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tee.1.html) utility instead.

```
ps aux | tee file
```

This usage (`| tee file`) is like `> file`, but it shows you the ouput as well. If you want to see the output and *append* it to the file (rather than overwriting), use the `-a` flag:

```
ps aux | tee -a file
```

That usage (`| tee -a file`) corresponds to `>> file`.

#### How does `tee` work?

`tee` duplicates its [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29), writing it both to the file (or list of files) given as its command-line arguments, and to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29).

Ordinarily--that is, when a program or command is run in the simplest way--its standard input is received from the user. It's what the user types as the program runs.

But [the *pipe* operator, `|`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), connects the standard output of the command to the left of it, to the standard input of the command to the right of it. In the examples above, this causes `ps aux` to send its output to the input of `tee` instead of to the terminal (and `tee` to receive its input from the output of `ps aux`, instead of from the terminal).

`tee` then writes what it's received both to *`file`* and to the terminal.

<sup>By the way, one common use of pipes is when you anticipate the output of a command will be long, and you want to be able to navigate up and down in it. You can then pipe its output to [`less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/less.1.html). For example: `dmesg | less`.</sup>

#### Redirecting/piping error output too.

The redirection and piping solutions discussed above and in [John1024's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/522643/22949) change where standard output goes, but they leave [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) alone. That is, most error messages (and some other messages, depending on the program) are unaffected--even in `ps aux > file`, errors will appear on the screen and *not* in file.

This is usually what you want. And especially in the case of `ps aux`, it's unlikely you want error messages in your output file--errors are unexpected, and you'd probably want to see them right away. An error would likely render the file you're trying to make unsuitable for your task, anyway, assuming your goal is to produce a table of running processes and their characteristics.

However, if you *do* want error output to be treated just the same as regular output, you can use the `&`-suffixed version of the redirection and piping operators:

- [`>&` (or `&>`)](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) in place of `>`: `ps aux >& file` or `ps aux &> file`
- [`&>>` (*not* `>>&`)](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Appending-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error) in place of `>>`: `ps aux &>> file`.
- [`|&` (*not* `&|`)](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines) in place of `|`: `ps aux |& tee file`, or `ps aux |& tee -a file to append.`

`bash`, the default interactive shell in Ubuntu, supports the `&`ed operators. This is the shell you're using unless you've deliberately switched to another one, so for interactive use (and for scripts where you know they'll be run with `bash`), you can definitely feel free to use it.

#### Redirecting/piping error output too, on shells that don't have the `&`ed operators.

Some shells (like `dash`, which [provides `sh` on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)) do not support them. In that case you'd get errors like:

- `dash: 2: Syntax error: Bad fd number` (when trying to use `>&` — in contrast, `&>` and `&>>`, when unsupported, get interpreted as `& >` and `& >>`, [which do something different](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists))
- `dash: 1: Syntax error: "&" unexpected` (when trying to use `|&`)

When working in a shell where `>&`, `>>&`, and `|&` are unsupported, you can send both standard output and standard error through a redirection or pipe in the traditional way, by specifying separately that standard error is first to be redirected to standard output.

This is achieved [with `2>&1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21). (`1` is the [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for standard output, and `2` is the file descriptor for standard error.)

For a *redirection* (i.e., when you'd like to be able to use `>&` or `>>&`), put `2>&1` at the very end:

```
ps aux > file 2>&1
```

```
ps aux >> file 2>&1
```

For a *pipe* (i.e., when you'd like to be able to use `|&`), put `2>&1` right before the `|` pipe:

```
ps aux 2>&1 | tee file
```

```
ps aux 2>&1 | tee -a file
```

Comment: Such a super reply thank you! I will test it out and report back later today :)

Comment: The redirection works awesome from terminal `ps aux >/home/noi/Desktop/me.txt` but can this `>/home/noi/Desktop/me.txt` be passed as command line argument? When I do that its not dumping to file :(

Comment: @Noitidart What are you trying to do exactly? Passed as a command-line argument to *what*? (And what is the goal?) My understanding of what you've said is that `ps aux >/home/noi/Desktop/me.txt` is working and the file `me.txt` on your desktop is being populated with the output of `ps aux`. If that's the case, what's "not dumping to file"? (If that's *not* the case, then I don't understand what you mean by "The redirection works awesome.") What works and what doesn't, exactly? Please tell about the full commands you're running, what you're hoping for or expecting, and what happens instead.

Comment: A sincere thanks for your time and trying to help me so much, I really apprecaite it. I added the code in post above. It uses [nsiProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProcess) to launch ps.

Comment: Solved it, john mentioned that he thinks it bypasses shell, so muru said to use bash and pass as string and it worked. A super super sincere thank you for this post, i used so much information from it in my 9 hours of testing! I will tell my friends about this post so they can see how useful it is and up vote you :)

Answer (score 2):

Unix programs typically write their output to "standard out", also known as stdout.  Using the shell feature of redirection, stdout can be sent to a file instead of the terminal.  To send it to a file name `file`, use:

```
ps aux >file
```

The symbol `>` indicates redirection and should be followed by a file name.  If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.  If you want to append to the existing file instead, use the symbol `>>` as in:

```
ps aux >>file
```

By the way, a very common use for redirection is to silence a verbose command.  To do this, one can redirect its output to the file `/dev/null`.  This is a special file which throws away any input that you send to it.

#### Working with scripts

Redirection can be used within a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux >file
```

Alternatively, redirection can be applied to the output of a script as a whole:

```
myscript >file
```

You can also pass the file name in as an argument.  Suppose that `myscript` consists of:

```
#!/bin/sh
ps aux >"$1"
```

(`$1` is script-ese for the first argument on the command-line.) Then you can run:

```
myscript somefile
```

and the `ps aux` command will be redirected to `somefile`.

Comment: Very nice simple answer for me to follow thank you very much!! :) Ill test out tonight and report back :)

Comment: The redirection works awesome from terminal `ps aux >/home/noi/Desktop/me.txt` but can this `>/home/noi/Desktop/me.txt` be passed as command line argument? When I do that its not dumping to file :(

Comment: @Noitidart It will work when used within a script.  However, you passing it as a "command line argument" to a script would be tricky.  To clarify your goals, please add the script to your question.

Comment: @Noitidart I updated the answer with some sentences on scripts.

Comment: Thank you man very much for trying to help me so patiently and so much. I added the code in post above. It uses [nsiProcess](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIProcess) to launch ps.

Comment: @Noitidart Thanks for the clarification. It appears to me that `runAsync` completely bypasses the shell.  In that case, all shell features like redirection are missing.  I suggest a separate question looking for answers from javascript/runAsync experts.

Comment: I think yo uwere right man thank you so much for that comment! I had to open bash and pass the argument as a string. A sincere thank you for all your help man!!! I accepted muru's solution but i will tell my friends about this post so they can see how useful it is and can up vote you. :)

Comment: Hey man your thought was correct: the `nsIProcess` doesn't suppoert shell features so that `>` feature so the `/bin/bash -c ps > ...` technique by @muru is the way to go. :)